# Mysql Order BY Speed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, query-optimization, mysql-5.7

There are 2 samples.

In the first example, it gives faster results when using orderby. (according to phpmyadmin speed report)

In the other example, I don't use order by, it gives slower results. (according to phpmyadmin speed report)

Isn't it unreasonable that it gives quick results when using Orderby?

The ranking doesn't matter to me, it's the speed that matters.

```
select bayi,tutar 
from siparisler 
where durum='1' and MONTH(tarih) = MONTH(CURDATE()) and YEAR(tarih) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
order by id desc
```

Speed: 0.0006

```
select bayi,tutar
from siparisler 
where durum='1' and MONTH(tarih) = MONTH(CURDATE()) and YEAR(tarih) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Speed: 0.7785

Comment: @Julia Bringing something as is is a separate matter.
Sorting and bringing is another matter.

Comment: What did the comparison of execution plans show?

Comment: @PM 77-1 speeds are already written above

Comment: [Execution plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) will show you how the query is being implemented and help you to explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Is the Query cache turned on?  Try again with `SQL SQL_NO_CACHE ...`

Answer (score 3):

An `order by` query will never execute faster than the same query without the `order by` clause. Sorting rows incurs more work for the database. In the best-case scenario, the sorting becomes a no-op because MySQL fetched the rows in the correct order in the first place: but that just make the two queries equivalent in terms of performance (it does not make the query that sorts faster).

Possibly, the results of the `order by` were cached already, so MYSQL gives you the result directly from the cache rather than actually executing the query.

If performance is what matters most to you, let me suggest to change the `where` predicate in order not to use date functions on the `tarih` column: such construct prevents the database to take advantage of an index (we say the predicate is non-SARGable). Consider:

```
select bayi, tutar 
from siparisler 
where 
    durum = 1 
    and tarih >= dateformat(current_date, '%Y-%m-01')
    and tarih <  dateformat(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') + interval 1 month
order by id desc
```

For performance with this query, consider an index on `(durum, tarih, id desc, bay, tutar)`: it should behave as a *covering index*, that MySQL can use to execute the entire query, without even looking at the actual data.

Comment: So this is from the cache.
As a result, does orderby slow down usage?

Comment: @othermember: yes - or, at least, it does not speed up the query, as explained in my answer.

Comment: So how can the default "order by id desc" be defined in any table in mysql?

Comment: @othermember: there is no such thing as *default order by*. You can, on the other hand, create the index I suggested: along with my version of the query, it should help MySQL speeding things up.

Comment: However, some of the sources I have read say that the query will be fast if an "index" is created. Is this the same as what I said?

Comment: @GMB . . . I don't think this is necessarily true.  There may be some cases where a very different execution plan is chosen and that happens to be faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: possibly... I guess these would qualify as edge cases though.

Comment: @GMB - You are referring to the "Query cache", which goes away with 8.0.  I suspect it was on when the timing were taken.

Answer (score 2):

At 0.0006s, you are almost certainly measuring the performance of the query_cache rather than the execution time. Try both queries again with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` and see what the performance difference is.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend writing the query as:

```
select bayi, tutar 
from siparisler p
where durum = 1 and -- no quotes assuming this is an integer 
      tarih >= curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate()) day;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(durm, tarih)`.

But that isn't your question.  It is possible that the `order by` could result in a radically different execution plan.  This is hypothetical, but the intention is to explain how this might occur.

Let me assume the following:

- The table only has an index on `(id desc, durum, tarih)`.
- The `where` clause matches few rows.
- The rows are quite wide.

The query without the `order by` would probably generate an execution plan that is a full table scan.  Because the rows are wide, lots of unnecessary data would be read.

The query with the `order by` could read the data in order *and then apply the where conditions*.  This would be faster than the other version, because only the rows that match the `where` conditions would be read in.

I cannot guarantee that this is happening.  But there are some counterintuitive situations that arise with queries.

Comment: Quotes around an _integer literal when compared to an integer column_ do not hurt performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze it through the `EXPLAIN` command, and then check the value corresponding to the type field, index or all

**Example:**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT bayi,tutar 
FROM siparisler 
WHERE durum='1' AND MONTH(tarih) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(tarih) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```